# Php artisan workerman:server not found when passed additional parameter "start"

Tags: laravel, sockets, laravel-artisan

php artisan command is listing workerman:server as a command.
php artisan command is asking for additional parameter while running `php artisan workerman:server`
But fails while passing "start"

Trailing output of "php artisan list":

```
session
  session:table        Create a migration for the session database table
 storage
  storage:link         Create a symbolic link from "public/storage" to "storage/app/public"
 vendor
  vendor:publish       Publish any publishable assets from vendor packages
 view
  view:clear           Clear all compiled view files
 workerman
  workerman:server     Run Workerman Server.
```

Output of "php artisan workerman:server"

```
surya@surya-u18:~/Projects/socket-workerman-sock$ php artisan workerman:server


  Not enough arguments (missing: "action").  


surya@surya-u18:~/Projects/socket-workerman-sock$
```

Output of "php artisan wokerman:server start"

```
surya@surya-u18:~/Projects/socket-workerman-sock$ php artisan workerman:server start
Unknown command: workerman:server
Usage: php yourfile <command> [mode]
Commands: 
start           Start worker in DEBUG mode.
                Use mode -d to start in DAEMON mode.
stop            Stop worker.
                Use mode -g to stop gracefully.
restart         Restart workers.
                Use mode -d to start in DAEMON mode.
                Use mode -g to stop gracefully.
reload          Reload codes.
                Use mode -g to reload gracefully.
status          Get worker status.
                Use mode -d to show live status.
connections     Get worker connections.
surya@surya-u18:~/Projects/socket-workerman-sock$
```

Already tried downgrading Laravel from 5.8 to 5.5.
No solution.

Answer (score 1):

in vendor change worker.php
commet  `static::parseCommand();` function.
      `public static function runAll(){
        self::checkSapiEnv();
        static::init();
        static::lock();
       // static::parseCommand();
        static::daemonize();
        static::initWorkers();
        static::installSignal();
        static::saveMasterPid();
        static::unlock();
        static::displayUI();
        static::forkWorkers();
        static::resetStd();
        static::monitorWorkers();
    }`

Comment: Why to change in vendor folder ? Isn't there any other solution ?